# Как заменить несколько одинаковых тегов xml при помощи xpath в yaml?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, groovy, yaml

Я с помощью xpath вытаскиваю значения тегов и заменяю с помощью replace в шаблоне ответа значения этих же тегов пустотой:

```
select:
  - xpath: //t:attributes/text()
    name: items
  - xpath: //t:attributes/text()
    name: attributesMO           
replace:
  - xpath: //items[position()>0]
    value: ''
  - xpath: //t:attributes[position()>0]
    value: ''
```

Но из-за того, что теги t:attributes и items может быть возвращены рандомное количество раз в ответе, то мой тест падает из-за этого. Какую конструкцию мне нужно добавить в мой шаблонный ответ, чтобы независимо от количества этих тегов я успешно зануливал их и тест не падал?

```
<s:AppData>
  <totalItems>0</totalItems>
  <items>
    <t:attributes/>
  </items>
</s:AppData>
```

Comment: То есть ответ может быть таким: https://ps.tmpc.ru/d356a13d9991